# Is there a way to make OS X Services (from Automator) work in GTK apps?

Tags: macos, automator, services

I’ve written a simple Service using Automator which takes a number in text and adds sales tax to it, replacing the original number, and a companion service which does the reverse.

I wrote these with Gnucash in mind, to save me time and the annoyance of having to have a terminal open with `calc` running in it.

Unfortunately, it seems that the service is not recognised within Gnucash for some reason. It seems that either GTK apps running on OS X do not support Services at all, or the text within Gnucash is not recognised as text by OS X and therefore the Service is not offered.

Has anyone successfully used Services with GTK apps? Is there a trick?

Please *don’t* answer with recommendations of alternate accounting applications (Gnucash suits my needs best for many reasons) or suggestions to use the tax tables in Gnucash (they are too limited for my purposes).

Comment: FYI : the GTK+ project, and anything GNU, is completely unaware of anything in OS X, unfortunately, and it is unlikely they ever will be. I think what you want might is a little bash, which should be academic to duplicate your Automator calculation service in. You could get a few bash scripts being specific about what you need done by posting at the [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) sister sites, or maybe here, but you need to let everyone know what it does exactly.

Comment: OS X just needs to be aware that the GTK+ text field is a “text field” in order for Services to work. This doesn’t seem outside the realm of possibility since there is already Mac-specific code to make GTK apps work on OS X. Anyway, I’m not sure how this could work in Bash. I could easily write a Bash script which does the calculation, but how would you then integrate that with the text fields in Gnucash?

Comment: Its not *really* an OS X native app... its an [X11 app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System)... but perhaps you are right... idk how though :/ just googled for a few mins, can't find anything about how.